# How to show different sub sites based on Member's user name In word press?

Tags: multisite, themes, password, membership

I have created a web site for a company with lots of sub sites using multisites in word press. These sub sites are password protected and those are for different clients.

Lets say for an example :- my main site is www.example.com

```
  and I have two sub sites called :- www.example.com/client_one  
                                     www.example.com/client_two
```

I want to have the client login window in my main site (www.example.com), with username and password.

What i want to do is, If a Member from client one place enter his or her given username and password correctly then i want to redirect them in to www.example.com/client_one/landing page.

same way for other member from client two to ---> www.example.com/client_two/landing page

is it possible to do in word press ? Do I need any plugins to do that?

Comment: Here is the answer for this question    http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/topic/13452

Comment: Can you post this as an Answer (including the solution code)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter called [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) which you can use. The third parameter passed to this filter is the user object, so you have all kinds of possibilities to redirect. Like this:

```
add_filter ('login_redirect', 'wpse63660_redirect', 10, 3);

function wpse63660_redirect ($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place (dashboard
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            // set redirect page based on user name or whatever you want
            if ($user->name == 'user1') $redirect_to = www.example.com/client_one
            elseif ... and so on ...
            return $redirect_to;
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
```